# Two differents request, two differents Calls and One Recycler

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I am trying to do this..

[image: please click here for checking the image].

I am consuming two different requests resources from the same API and in MainActivity doing two different calls. But, I can't show the content I want from both JSON on one RecyclerView view.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String TAG = "Football";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ListaPartidosAdapter listaPartidosAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        listaPartidosAdapter = new ListaPartidosAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listaPartidosAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, VERTICAL, true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.football-data.org/v2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        obtenerDatos();
    }

    private void obtenerDatos() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String todayDate=df.format(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,3);
        String endDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());

        Log.i(TAG, "todayDate : " + todayDate);
        Log.i(TAG, "endDate : " + endDate);

        footballdataService service = retrofit.create(footballdataService.class);
        Call<PartidosRespuesta> partidosRespuestaCall = service.obtenerlistaPartidos(todayDate,endDate);
        Call<StandingsRespuesta> standingsRespuestaCall = service.obtenerStandings();

        partidosRespuestaCall.enqueue(new Callback<PartidosRespuesta>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PartidosRespuesta> call, Response<PartidosRespuesta> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    PartidosRespuesta partidosRespuesta = response.body();
                    List<Partido> listaPartidos = partidosRespuesta.getMatches();
                    listaPartidosAdapter.adicionarListaPartidos((ArrayList<Partido>) listaPartidos);

                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PartidosRespuesta> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });


        standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue(new Callback<StandingsRespuesta>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StandingsRespuesta> call, Response<StandingsRespuesta> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    StandingsRespuesta standingsRespuesta = response.body();
                    List<Stand> listaStands = standingsRespuesta.getStandings();
                    listaPartidosAdapter.adicionarListaStands((ArrayList<Stand>) listaStands);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StandingsRespuesta> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I say before, each request has a different enqueue Call. I don't know if it is the right way of do it but think yes because each call has its own service.

**ListaPartidosAdapter.java**

```
public class ListaPartidosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaPartidosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "Football_Adapter";
    private ArrayList<Partido> dataset;
    private ArrayList<Stand> dataset_stand;
    private Context context;

    public ListaPartidosAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataset = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.dataset_stand = new ArrayList<Stand>();
    }

    @Override
    public ListaPartidosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_partidos, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListaPartidosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Partido p = dataset.get(position);
        String status = p.getStatus();

        if (status.equals("SCHEDULED")){
            String status_ = "SCH";
            holder.status.setText(status_);
        }
        holder.utcDate.setText(p.getUtcDate());


        Partido.EquipoCasa homeTeam = p.getHomeTeam();
        String id_homeTeam = homeTeam.getId();

        holder.homeTeam.setText(homeTeam.getName());

        Partido.EquipoVisita awayTeam = p.getAwayTeam();
        holder.awayTeam.setText(awayTeam.getName());

        Stand s = dataset_stand.get(position);
        Stand.Table table = (Stand.Table) s.getTable();
        Stand.Table.Equipo team = (Stand.Table.Equipo) table.getEquipo();
        String id_equipo = team.getId();
        holder.homeTeam.setText(team.getName());


        if(id_homeTeam.equals(id_equipo)){
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(team.getCrestUrl())
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.team);
            //holder.team.setImageDrawable(team.getCrestUrl());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size()+dataset_stand.size();
    }


    public void adicionarListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> listaPartidos){
        dataset.addAll(listaPartidos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void adicionarListaStands(ArrayList<Stand> listaStands){
        dataset_stand.addAll(listaStands);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView status;
        private TextView utcDate;
        private TextView homeTeam;
        private TextView awayTeam;
        public ImageView team;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            utcDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.utcDate);
            homeTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeTeam);
            awayTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayTeam);
            team = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes in this line. **Stand s = dataset_stand.get(position);**, if a comment it with code below, **It works without using the second JSON or the second request** but as I showed on image I want to merge two different requests on the same RecyclerView view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement

> The problem comes in this line. **Stand s = dataset_stand.get(position);**, if a comment it with code below, **It works without using the second JSON or the second request.**

Yes, it's expected. Why? Because you're calling [`RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) method inside `adicionarListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> listaPartidos)` after inserting data to ArrayList in `RecyclerView` array adapter class which informs `ArrayAdapter` to redraw/refresh components inside `RecyclerView` container.

Now `RecycelrView` starts binding component within the `onBindViewHolder(ListaPartidosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)` method. So, what's happening here?

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListaPartidosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Partido p = dataset.get(position);
    String status = p.getStatus();

    if (status.equals("SCHEDULED")){
        String status_ = "SCH";
        holder.status.setText(status_);
    }
    holder.utcDate.setText(p.getUtcDate());


    Partido.EquipoCasa homeTeam = p.getHomeTeam();

    // other code

    Stand s = dataset_stand.get(position);  // <====== the problem 

    // other code

}
```

Your `dataset_stand` list will be empty (size of the list is 0) until you get data/response from `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` method in your activity.

Keep in mind that Retrofit's [`Call#enque()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) method is Asynchronous. Which means in your case `obtenerDatos()` method executes top to bottom in a single hit. You only get data when `Retrofit` returns success response with `onResponse()` method.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to comment out the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method inside `adicionarListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> listaPartidos)`. Like below

```
public void adicionarListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> listaPartidos){
   dataset.addAll(listaPartidos);
  //  notifyDataSetChanged();   // <======  just COMMENT OUT this line
}
```

This will prevent `onBindViewHolder()` being called. When the second request `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` completes it's operation, as per your code notifies dataset changed. Like below.

```
public void adicionarListaStands(ArrayList<Stand> listaStands){
   dataset_stand.addAll(listaStands);
   notifyDataSetChanged();    // <==== DO NOT remove this
}
```

**Side Note:** Your code is problematic. You're using multiple request to fill a single RecyclerView container. Your RecyclerView fails to display record if `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` fails to get response from server.

**PS:** Please check method names I mentioned in my answer properly and alter the code accordingly. Do not get confused with the method names.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.Yeah, the code is problematic, but, I don't know how to get the data on an unique request if they comes from two different resources. About the answer, if I comment the notifyDataSetChanged from adicionarListaPartidos(), effectively, the app compile on a right way but, it doesn't show anything on screen, neither names and utcdata neither shield. If I comment the problematic line and uncomment the notifyDataSetChanged it works, but just, using the first request, following the image.

Comment: I guess the `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` is not returning proper data. Confirm that both `dataset` and `dataset_stand` are non-empty i.e, API is returning records properly and parsing data into POJO is fine. I'd suggest you to debug the code in `ListaPartidosAdapter` class, specially `onBindViewHolder()` part. Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Yeah, you are right, standingsRespuesta.Call.enque() is no passing data to dataset_stand. dataset_stand has size 0 while dataset has 6. ¿How do I fix it?. I am learning with JAVA and Android

Comment: Again if you start debugging your code, you may get the root cause the error. Put breakpoint inside `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` and confirm that the API request is successful and it's returning proper JSON data.

Comment: Yeahh I did it, but, inside of standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue() it doesn't show me anything, I mean, Android doesn't debug there. I was thinking on RxJava2,but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Debug `standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue()` I mean, what does it returns inside `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` method? You need to put break-point both inside `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods. And about RxJava2 I'm also not aware of it. I also about to learn RxJava. I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Yeah.., I'm trying to debug there. I debugged inside partidosRespuestaCall.enqueue() and got response from Android about HTTP Request. When I try to debug inside standingsRespuestaCall.enqueue() Android doesn't open the debug console.

Comment: Try to [Log](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) the success and failure messages (specially response and t objects in methods) in that method. That would definitely help you in debugging the code. :)